# Does a .gitignore file apply to all branches?

Tags: git, github

Does a .gitignore file in Master branch apply to other branches?

In section "Create a local .gitignore" in https://help.github.com/en/articles/ignoring-files, it doesn't specify which branch you should be in.

Answer (score 5):

`.gitignore` applies to files in the *folder* that the `.gitignore` file is in; it does not matter which branch you currently have selected. Any files specified in the `.gitignore` will be excluded from Git.

Note that the references in `.gitignore` are recursive, so if you have a `.gitignore` file at the root level of your project, it will apply the rules to all files and folders within your project.

Comment: Worth noting: files that are already tracked won't be ignored: listing an already-committed file doesn't cause it to become excluded.

Comment: Thanks Obsidian Age. Little confused as others seem to suggest that each branch needs it's own though!

@torek so does that mean .gitignore files are something you should try to  _get right_ right at the start of a project? Usually I find it a little more iterative: like I realise I need to add something because it's showing up as Changed in GitHub Desktop.

Comment: @w4rner: it's good, but not *required*, to get them right initially. (The definition of "right" may evolve, which can make this impossible.) The problem that occurs when you get it "wrong" is that some commit(s) have a copy of a file that you'd like them not to have, and since no *existing* commit (as identified by its raw hash ID) can ever be changed, you're now stuck with that. How bad *that* is, well, that depends: it can be quite mild, or a major pain in the butt.

Comment: What you can change is *new* commits. To remove a file that's tracked, use `git rm`, which removes the file from the *index* (aka staging area) and the *work-tree*. You can see the files in the work-tree, but you can only see the index copies sort of indirectly. See other StackOverflow postings or a really good Git tutorial or book; there isn't room to describe this well in a comment.

Comment: Understood  adding a .gitignore can't remove previous commits, but does it straight away remove it from future commits, or do you have to do git rm as well @torek

Comment: @w4rner: if the file is in Git's index, you will have to run `git rm` or equivalent. This returns us to the question of when the file is in Git's index, which is the crucial one here. The file *is* in Git's index when either (a) you put it there, or (b) Git puts it there. If it's not already there, listing the file in `.gitignore` helps prevent situation (a), but has no effect on situation (b): checking out any existing commit that *does* have the file will put the file in Git's index, and you'll have to run `git rm` (or equivalent) again, each time.

Answer (score 3):

Different branches may contain different `.gitignore` files, and each one applies to the branches it appears on. To make rules that apply to all branches, edit `.git/info/exclude`.

The [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) covers multiple files that can contain ignore patterns.

> Which file to place a pattern in depends on how the pattern is meant
>   to be used.
>
> - Patterns which should be version-controlled and distributed to other repositories via clone (i.e., files that all developers will want to
>     ignore) should go into a `.gitignore` file.
> - Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do not need to be shared with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary
>     files that live inside the repository but are specific to one user’s
>     workflow) should go into the `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` file.
> - Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice)
>     generally go into a file specified by `core.excludesFile` in the user’s
>     `~/.gitconfig`. Its default value is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`. If
>     `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/ignore` is used instead.

Your question asked about a `.gitignore` file on the master branch and thus corresponds to the first bullet.

Ignore patterns apply to the branches they appear on and more specifically to the directory subtree where each is found, perhaps overridden by `.gitignore` files in deeper directories. Also from the docs:

> - Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These patterns match relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file. A project normally includes such `.gitignore` files in its repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.

Answer (score 0):

As [Obsidian Age said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58332209/1256452), it applies to the files in the sub-tree rooted at the point in which the `.gitignore` file appears.

A `.gitignore` file *should be*<sup>1</sup> tracked (i.e., should be present in the index) and therefore exist as a copy in each commit.  This means *each commit has its own `.gitignore` copy*.<sup>2</sup>  If you're on `branch-1` and you `git checkout branch-2` and that brings out a *different* `.gitignore` file, *its* contents now apply to the folder and subfolders.  If you then `git checkout branch-1` to bring back the `branch-1` files, including the `branch-1` version of `.gitignore`, *those* contents now apply.

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't a hard requirement, but *not* committing the `.gitignore` file means you probably should not be using a `.gitignore` file at all.  You can get a similar effect by creating either a global gitignore (for yourself), or a `.git/info/excludes` file for this one repository.

<sup>2</sup>As with all tracked-and-committed files, Git *shares* **any** file that exactly matches.  It can do this because *every* committed file is frozen forever in *that particular form, in that particular commit*.  It can't be changed, so it *can* be *shared*.

That is, suppose you `git checkout master`, create a ten-megabyte file named `big`, run `git add big`, and then `git commit`.  You've now created a new 10-MB file that is in the commit you just made.  *Every commit you make after this point also has a 10-MB file in it,* up until you `git rm big` to remove it from the index-and-work-tree and make all future commits *not* have the file.<sup>3</sup>  **But** every file that shares that exact *version* of the big file, uses one single shared copy.  So if you have four thousand commits, but they all have just that one particular file `big`, you only have 10 MB of `big`, not 4000*10 MB.

<sup>3</sup>Or, of course, you could overwrite `big` with tiny contents.  The *next* commit you make will have a small file named `big`, which will get shared with every future commit, just as the big file named `big` got shared with every future commit up to this point.

If that's too confusing, just think of Git as automatically doing a "see if this data ever got committed before" de-duplication pass, every time you `git add` a file.  If it *did* ever get committed before, Git automatically re-uses the already-frozen copy.